# How do I go through each element in this javascript object and print out each name?

Tags: javascript

```
thejson = [ { name: 'Jany', id: '1246956' },
            { name: 'Azeez', id: '2246306' },
            { name: 'William', id: '22525926' },
          ]
```

How do I use a "foreach" loop and print out each name?

Comment: It is not JSON. It is an array of objects.

Comment: Oh thats right. It's not json haha. I get it, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps reword the title of the question, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < thejson.length; i++) {
    alert(thejson[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
thejson.forEach(function (e) { printOut(e.name); });
```

should do the trick. You'll have to define "printOut" of course.

If you're concerned about older browser compatibility, this works:

```
for (var i = 0, len = thejson.length; i < len; i++) {
  printOut(thejson[i].name);
}
```

Should work on every browser back to the dawn of Javascript.

Comment: `forEach` was added in JS 1.6. There are plenty of people using browsers that don't support it.